# Applying the @staticmethod, python3

Tags: python, static-methods

```
class UserInput():
    users=[]
    def __init__(self, name,lista,listb,listc,listd):
        self.name=""
        self.lista=lista
        self.listb=listb
        self.listc=listc
        self.listd=listd


    @staticmethod
    def create_new_user(x):
        x=userinput("x","","","","")
        users.append(x)
```

Im intending on making a function where new users are generated, only returning a name to the user and no lists yet, hence x in the name slot.

**My Question:** is this the correct usage of `@staticmethod` or did I miss the entire point of it?

To my understanding, it allows the user to use,in this case, `userinput.create_new_user('tim')` without having the class already pre-defined, tim=userinput("foo","","","","");it creates it on the spot.

### What I was trying to turn the function `create_new_users` into:

```
@staticmethod
def create_new_user():
    print("how many users do you want to create")
    x=int(input())
    y=0
    while y < x:
        print("assign the users names")
        name = input("")
        if name == "" or "None,none":
            raise SyntaxError("name cannot be None or empty")
            break

        name=userinput("","","","","")      
        userinput.users.append(name)
        y+=1
```

Comment: Please correct you indentation.

Comment: There are also syntax errors here

Comment: sorry I forget everytime

Comment: @qwwqwwq now that I fixed indentation as well as some obvious syntax,append(x) to nothing changed to users.append(x), it is working

Comment: `tim=userinput("foo","","","","");` does not create a class, but an instance of it. The class is created as soon as the `class ...:` body is executed.

Comment: @glglgl that's what I meant sorry, im wanting to create instances of classes which can then be found in the user list for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `@classmethod` will be the easiest alternative for that.

```
class UserInput: # capitals! Look at PEP 8.
    users = [] # rearranged to the top for better readability

    def __init__(self, name, lista, listb, listc, listd):
        self.name = ""
        self.lista = lista
        self.listb = listb
        self.listc = listc
        self.listd = listd

    @classmethod
    def create_new_user(cls): # no need for x if you overwrite it immediately
        x = cls("x", "", "", "", "")
        cls.users.append(x) # easier access to this static attribute
        return x # for the caller having access to it as well.
```

It works as well if we subclass `UserInput` as it uses the new class then.

But note that `x = cls("x", "", "", "", "")` won't be very useful, though; better do

```
    @classmethod
    def create_new_user(cls, *a, **k): # no need for x if you overwrite it immediately
        x = cls(*a, **k) # pass the arguments given by the caller to __init__.
        cls.users.append(x) # easier access to this static attribute
        return x # for the caller having access to it as well.
```

I can use that now this way:

```
a = UserInput("foo", "whatever", "is", "needed", "here")
```

or, if I choose to,

```
a = UserInput.create_new_user("foo", "whatever", "is", "needed", "here")
```

which additionally appends the new user to the list.

If you want to be able to shorten the arguments list, you can do so as well:

```
    def __init__(self, name, lista=None, listb=None, listc=None, listd=None):
        self.name = name
        self.lista = lista if lista is not None else []
        self.listb = listb if listb is not None else []
        self.listc = listc if listc is not None else []
        self.listd = listd if listd is not None else []
```

if they are really lists. If they are strings, another name would be appropriate and, as strings are immutable, you can simply do

```
    def __init__(self, name, lista='', listb='', listc='', listd=''):
        self.name = name
        self.lista = lista
        self.listb = listb
        self.listc = listc
        self.listd = listd
```

and call the stuff with

```
a = UserInput.create_new_user("foo", listc=...) # all others are left empty
b = UserInput("bar") # all are left empty
c = UserInput.create_new_user("ham", lista=..., listd=...) # all others are left empty
```

---

Now that you come up with a different task, I'll try to cope with that as well:

```
@classmethod
def create_new_users(cls): # several users!
    print("how many users do you want to create")
    num = int(input())
    for _ in range(num): # simpler iteration
        print("enter the user's name")
        name = input("") # in 3.x, this is always a string, so it cannot be None...
        # if name == "" or "None,none": # That won't work as you think.
        if name == '' or name.lower() == 'none': # but why disallow the string 'None'?
            # raise SyntaxError("name cannot be None or empty")
            raise RuntimeError("name cannot be None or empty") # or ValueError or alike
            # break not needed. raise jumps out without it as well.
        user = cls(name, "", "", "", "") # name is an input, not an output.
        cls.users.append(name)
```

But I wonder if the class is really the right place to store new users, and only those created with this function. Maybe it would be better to feed the `users` list directly in `__init__` and let this function be at a higher level.

---

The advantage of using a `@classmethod` here is that you always work on the corret basis.

Imagine you have a `UserInput` with a `__init__()` method as above. Then you can subclass it and do

`UserInput.create_new_users()`Using a @classmethod will be the easiest alternative for that.

```
class UserInputStoring(UserInput):
    users = [] # this is only here, not at the parent.
    def __init__(self, *a, **k):
        super(UserInputStoring, self).__init__(*a, **k) # pass everything up as it was used
        self.users.append(self)
```

Now you can have your `create_new_users()` in the base class and be a `@classmethod` and it will pick the right `__init__` to call depending on how you call it.

Comment: the not capitalizing was mainly due to laziness, once I'm finished ill go back and correct capitalization and such

Comment: I added that answer just to show to show you the code that it ended up being since when I tried adding it into a comment it kept removing the structure and organizing it into paragraph form

Comment: Im not understanding the difference between our examples, both seem to return the some information to the same list, can you explain how ours differ other than the fact one is `@classmethod`, the other `@staticmethod`. Both are accessed by `userinput.create_new_users()`;yours uses the required `cls` argument. So in your example userinput is returned as the cls argument, where mine doesn't require a cls.In both examples I can use userinput parent class to use the function and it appears both return the same values.What is our differences?Other than the fact yours is shortened down in some areas

Comment: it uses `cls` implicitly is what I mean. Unless the same `@staticmethod` can be used in other classes I cannot see the major differences in our example other than one using the `cls` implicitly

Comment: @TimLayne There is no big difference, but a `@classmethod` works as well with subclasses. One example: You might separate the storing in the list into the `__init__` of a subclass. Then the caller can choose if he uses `UserInput.create_new_users()` for not storing the list or `UserInputStoring.create_new_users()` for storing the list.

Comment: ahhhh, I understand. I can define a @classmethod within the parent class and subclasses can use it as well, but don't subclasses already inherit the parents functions? Unless `@staticmethods` cannot be inherited?

Comment: @Tim They do, but with a `@staticmethod` you always call the same `__init__()`, leaving no room for variation. A `@classmethod` gets nodified about the class it was called with and thus can use it for instantiating, picking the right `__init__` depending on if you want to add the new users to the list or not.

Comment: I understand now what you saying completely, I see that although the methods are similar, in most cases the `@classmethod` is more applicable and flexible. Thank you for explaining them

Answer (score 3):

in a static method you could not use the class variable, your code should get

```
NameError: global name 'users' is not defined
```

**edit:**

use `userinput.users.append`

Comment: Right, but how is that an answer?

Comment: yes that does happen, then it would be better to use class method in this case? `@staticmethod` must not allow references to any class variables.That would mean id have to have a a global list already created for my function to work; would it be more beneficial then to just turn the `@staticmethod` and the function under it into a `@classmethod`?

Comment: that is the correct usage, I just needed to refer to the list within the class. Thanks

Comment: @TimLayne I'd definitely use a `@classmethod` here.

Comment: @glglgl why do you think `@classmethod` would work better in this situation? if I use `@classmethod` I have to have  class created before I can even use that function, where as in my case I can use that function right off the bat.

Comment: @TimLayne But without having the class, you cannot use its methods. I'll write a separate answer.